# How can i select this span element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am just starting with Selenium and now in need to select this element:

```
<span class=" close">Matrices</span>
```

This line of code returns zero elements, so i guess it's not the right one :-)

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> matrixLink = driver.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText("Matrices"));
```

But I could not find another one suitable, besides the Xpath, but that looks like this (`//*[@id=\"Navigation\"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[7]/span`), and that seems a bit fragile to me?

**EDIT**:
the span has the class 'close'.
It's part of a menu, where there are 19 span's with the class 'close' so it's not a unique selector unfortunately....

Comment: so the span has an empty class?

Comment: Ah, good one, it has NOT, it has only no class when clicked on it, i'll edit the question. However, it's a menu item, and i checked it: i've got 19 span (menu items) with the class 'close' and the clicked item has the 'close' class removed from it.

Comment: Does `//*[@id=\"Navigation\"]/descendant::span[text()='Matrices']` work?

Comment: is it correct that the PartialLinkText does not give a result? Is the PartialLinkText not suited for this?

Comment: Yeah, that works! So i should work on my xpath or check with the selenium IDE...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

```
//*[@id=\"Navigation\"]/descendant::span[text()='Matrices']
```

Note that if you can, be specific in your XPath queries, mainly to aid readability and improve performance...that is the `*` in your query will query **all** elements in the page. I don't know what kind of element the **Navigation** element is, but you should put it's exact element type in, for instance if it's a div, make it:

```
//div[@id=\"Navigation\"]/descendant::span[text()='Matrices']
```

A slight explanation for this XPath is that it will grab the `Navigation` element, and simply look *anywhere inside it* to find a `span` element that has the text of `Matrices`. Without the `descendant` bit in the XPath, it would only search for **direct children**. That means elements that a child of `Navigation`, nothing else - so if an element is a child of `TestDiv` which is a child of `Navigation`, `descendant` would catch it, without it you won't return any results.

As for why `By.PartialLinkText` would not work, this would only search for anchor links. It is common, as you have seen, that anchor links have a `span` element inside them or sometimes it is just a `span` on it's own.

`By.PartialLinkText` and similarly `By.LinkText` would not 'see' this element, since it's not an anchor element.

Comment: That last paragraph is most important.  "Link" means `<a>`, `<span>` doesn't qualify.

Comment: Regarding the XPath readability, you could write this expression as `id('Navigation')//span[text()='Matrices']` (the first function call being the XPath [`id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id) function, [`//` being shorthand for `::descendant-or-self::`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) which in general case (there is an exception) is usable instead of just `descendant::`, because it's shorter).

Answer (score 2):

My favorite problem solver for these cases:

- Install [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/plugins.jsp)
- Click the link you need
- In the "target" in Selenium IDE you will see different xpath possibilities

But I would use the approach, that its N-th element with "close" class (`//span[7]` or something like that)

Comment: Yes, the xpath with the 7th element works, but that seems so fragile, when the menu gets an extra item it's no longer the 7th item...

Comment: Agreed. In my cases it works perfectly, because the changes in Web GUI are not that often nor that invasive

Answer (score 2):

You can use //span[text()='Matrices']
It will select your element.